# how to ignore null values while dropping the matched pattern in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, null, match

I have a data frame, from where I want to match with a pattern and then drop the unmatched rows from the data frame. So, for doing that I have used `str.contains`, while I am dropping it. I am getting an error saying that `Can't mask null values`. How to ignore the bull values while dropping them?

```
My code:

df = 
   a   b
0  2   3
1      5
2 34we 9
3  4   9

df[df['a'].str.contains(r'^\d+$')]

Error: 'Can't mask Naan Values


Excepted output:

   a   b
0  2   3
1      5
3  4   9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `na=True` in `str.contains` function to assign `nan` as `True`:

```
In [907]: df[df['a'].str.contains(r'^\d+$', na=True)]
Out[907]: 
     a  b
0    2  3
1       5
3    4  9
```